# Declaring variable as Arena.Application generates Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, simulation, arena-simulation

I received this error even though I select the "Arena 16.0 Type Library".

[image]

Comment: The code you show is written for early binding. So you need to [add the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference) to the Arena Library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim oModel as Object
Set oModel = CreateObject("Arena.Application")
```

Comment: The OP woul better add the reference as the next error will probably occur at the line `Dim m as Arena.Model`.

Comment: How can I open the software and run a model after writing that code?